# Playing YUV video using mplayer in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to play yuv format video in mplayer. i am having the yuv file is binny.yuv

> mplayer binny.yuv -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=856:h=480

but is not playing,the result i got is

> MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
>   mplayer: could not connect to socket
>   mplayer: No such file or directory
>   Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
>   Playing y.yuv.
>   rawvideo file format detected.
>   Load subtitles in ./
>   Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
> Opening video decoder: [raw] RAW Uncompressed Video
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
[swscaler @ 0x9e99ec0] using unscaled yuv420p -> yuv420p special converter
VO: [xv] 856x480 => 856x480 Planar YV12 
Selected video codec: [rawi420] vfm: raw (RAW I420)
```

Still i need to install anything????

Answer (score -3):

`ffmpeg` and `mplayer` are well know to be buggy and discontinued by the ffmpeg team, and I can confirm that according to my personal experience, you should use `avconv` instead.

look at the examples from the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html).

Comment: "ffmpeg ... known to be buggy and discontinued".  While this opinion might be forgiven in '13 because of a lot of confusion at that time, fast forward to today and regardless of which side of the ffmpeg/libav thing you side with, ffmpeg certainly must be acknowledged to be alive and well.